# Multiprocess with shared variable in bash

Tags: bash, synchronization, multiprocessing, progress-bar, shared-variable

I'm trying to achieve a dynamic progress bar in bash script, the kind we see when installing new packages. In order to do this, a *randomtask* would call a *progressbar* script as a background task and feed it with some integer values.

The first script uses a pipe to feed the second.

```
#!/bin/bash
# randomtask

pbar_x=0            # percentage of progress
pbar_xmax=100

while [[ $pbar_x != $pbar_xmax ]]; do
    echo "$pbar_x"
    sleep 1
done | ./progressbar &

# do things
(( pbar_x++ ))

# when task is done
(( pbar_x = pbar_xmax ))
```

Hence, the second script needs to constantly receive the integer, and print it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# progressbar

while [ 1 ]; do
    read x
    echo "progress: $x%"
done
```

But here, the second script doesn't receive the values as they are updated. What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on WSL, which means I can't use mkfifo. And coproc seemed to perfectly answer my need, so I searched and eventually found this:
[coproc usage with exemples [bash-hackers wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc).

We start the process with `coproc` and redirect its output to *stdout*:

```
{ coproc PBAR { ./progressbar; } >&3; } 3>&1
```

Then we can access its in and out via *file descriptors* `${PBAR[0]}`(output) and  `${PBAR[1]}`(input)

```
    echo "$pbar_x" >&"${PBAR[1]}"
```

**randomtask**

```
#!/bin/bash

pbar_x=0            # percentage of progress
pbar_xmax=100

{ coproc PBAR { ./progressbar; } >&3; } 3>&1

while (( pbar_x <= 10)); do
    echo $(( pbar_x++ )) >&"${PBAR[1]}"
    sleep 1
done

# do things
echo $(( pbar_x++ )) >&"${PBAR[1]}"

# when task is done
echo $(( pbar_x = pbar_xmax )) >&"${PBAR[1]}"
```

**progressbar**

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x; do
    echo "progress: $x%"
done
```

Please note that :

> The coproc keyword is not specified by POSIX(R).
>
> The coproc keyword appeared in Bash version 4.0-alpha

Answer (score 0):

That can't work, the `while` loop is running in a subprocess, changes in the main program will not affect it in any way.

There are several IPC mechanisms, here I use a *named pipe* (FIFO):

```
pbar_x=0            # percentage of progress
pbar_xmax=100
pipename="mypipe"

# Create the pipe 
mkfifo "$pipename"

# progressbar will block waiting on input
./progressbar < "$pipename" &

while (( pbar_x != pbar_xmax )); do
     #do things
     (( pbar_x++ ))
     echo "$pbar_x"
     sleep 1
     # when task is done
     #(( pbar_x = pbar_xmax ))
done > "$pipename"

rm "$pipename"
```

I also modified `progressbar`:

```
# This exits the loop when the pipe is closed
while read x
do
    echo "progress: $x%"
done
```

With a third script you could use *process substitution* instead.

Comment: With a third script ? What would the third script do then ?

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this with coproc, and redirecting the child process output to standard output ?

Comment: @GabrielForien:  maybe, that's what coprocs are supposed to do.  I have used them with `ksh` for this type of thing, but never had any success with the bash version.